# Rails / Gem command suddenly throwing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I was in the midst of Ruby on Rails coding, having run several rails generate methods over the last hour, when suddenly a new generate command threw up an error message. A similar error came when I tried to run my tests via rake. And then on the command line for just "rails". And then the same error for the "gem" command.

So I presume, somehow, I have broken my "rubygems" Gem file ? Which is worrying, as I was coding in Rubymine and, well frankly, nowhere near it !

Can anyone help explain what might have happened, and what the best fix might be ? For now, I'll try reinstalling Ruby, but that's a costly workaround I'd like to avoid doing more than once.

The error stacktrace looks as follows :

```
C:\Users\Ben>rails
C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127:in `load_gems_in':
private method `load' called for Gem::Specification:Class (NoMethodError)
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb:38:in `skip_during'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:126:in `load_gems_in'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:125:in `each'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:125:in `load_gems_in'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:122:in `reverse_each'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:122:in `load_gems_in'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:321:in `refresh!'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:97:in `initialize'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1051:in `new'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1051:in `source_index'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:243:in `activate_dep'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/bin/rails:18
```

My Gem file (for the project above) is:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem "jquery-rails"
```

Although the error occurs at all command line instances.

[EDIT] at this stage I have fully reinstalled ruby and rails and the problem has gone. I have kept the old installation directory though, in case we can get to the bottom of this issue, or in case it reoccurs !

[SECOND EDIT]New installation, after a machine reboot, gem has once more started failing, and RubyMine is saying it can't find any gems (even rubygems) :

```
C:\Users\Ben>gem
C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1433:in `private': undefined method `search' for class `OptionParser' (NameError)
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1433
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command.rb:7
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:7
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:7
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from C:/dev/lang/Ruby187/bin/gem:9
```

Maybe RubyMine is screwing up the install ? Or Windows 7 ? Never has a problem with my core development language getting corrupted - very frustrating !

Comment: rails and gem commands working correctly in other project environment? Can you create new rails project in another dir? Add your Gemfile contents to question text.

Comment: The rails and gem commands are failing in all envrionments (both via Rubymine and command line invocation). Cannot do ANYTHING rails related, as all commands throw an error such as the one above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hunch was correct - RubyMine was to blame... and the user too, of course !

Far too used to using refactoring tools in Intellij for Java, I refactored some fairly common methods names in my controllers (such as changing "show" to "index") and ended up refactoring into the Ruby 1.8 standard library files too !

Need to double-check what refactoring is doing, going forward, and try to limit it just to my project and not the whole SDK :)